# (S3 Backend not working )Spring Config Server: Not able to get profiles content from AWS S3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 as a backend for Spring Config server. I uploaded 3 files in the my bucket.

1. application-local.properties
2. application-prod.properties
3. application-qa.properties

Then I am trying to hit REST API endpoint as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_quick_start).

URL: `http://localhost:4000/application/qa`

After 9 seconds I get a 200 response, below is the body.

```
    "name": "application",
    "profiles": [
        "qa"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": []
}
```

Technically I should get data in propertySources but I'm not getting anything.

###### Config Server application.properties

```
server.port=4000
debug=true

# AWS credentials
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=*************
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=******************************
cloud.aws.region=ap-south-1

spring.profiles.active=awss3
spring.cloud.config.server.awss3.region=ap-south-1
spring.cloud.config.server.awss3.bucket=mybucket


# Spring Admin server port 
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:2000/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
```

###### Config Server logs

```
2021-10-21 22:54:21.820  INFO 33105 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.a.c.ConfigserverApplication          : Started ConfigserverApplication in 0.346 seconds (JVM running for 2822.873)
2021-10-21 22:54:21.821 DEBUG 33105 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2021-10-21 22:54:21.823  INFO 33105 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2021-10-21 22:54:21.823 DEBUG 33105 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2021-10-21 22:54:23.429  INFO 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-10-21 22:54:23.429  INFO 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-10-21 22:54:23.429 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2021-10-21 22:54:23.429 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2021-10-21 22:54:23.429 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2021-10-21 22:54:23.430 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@1122dbe3
2021-10-21 22:54:23.430 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@1fe527b7
2021-10-21 22:54:23.430 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2021-10-21 22:54:23.430  INFO 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-10-21 22:54:23.430 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/application/qa", parameters={}
2021-10-21 22:54:23.431 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController#defaultLabel(String, String)
2021-10-21 22:54:32.853 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json]
2021-10-21 22:54:32.855 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [Environment [name=application, profiles=[qa], label=null, propertySources=[], version=null, state=nu (truncated)...]
2021-10-21 22:54:32.856 DEBUG 33105 --- [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that might help. If you are on a version of Spring Boot >= 2.4, the property `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true` needs to be supplied as a command-line argument or via the maven starter [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap). That property has to be read before the "bootstrap" phase before `application.properties|yml` is read.

It could be related to the following:

- IAM access to the selected buckets
- Credentials - I have only used the [provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) for authenticating against AWS S3 when using Config Server. [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/d8f6341f336e8da78eaab424ca3a3e82431f83db/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/AwsS3EnvironmentRepositoryFactory.java#L37), it seems like the provider chain is the only way to create the S3 client. Shame that you can't configure your own `AmazonS3` bean.

The response you're getting indicates that the app can talk to S3, but it cannot find the properties. Spring Config Server will report `DOWN` when hitting `/actuator/health` if it cannot communicate with S3. Does your app show as healthy in actuator?